# UIPageViewController; how to deal with dynamically changing data source

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I'm creating a dynamic "wizard-isch" step-by-step feature that basically will guide the user through a set of views involving both static views with instructions and information, and dynamic views requiring user-interferance (filling out text-fields, comm with backend, etc...) before allowing the user to proceed to the "next" view.

Hence, I figured that the UIPageViewController would be a nice approach, initially setting just one start-view controller to say "welcome";

```
[self setViewControllers:@[welcomeViewController]
               direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                animated:NO
              completion:nil];
```

And, then using the `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` to dynamically get the next views. That way, I can prevent the user from getting "too far" ahead, without first filling out required info on one view, before allowing the user to scroll to the next view with more instructions, etc etc...

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    //Check if the user has filled out everything that needs to be done

    //If all is good, allow for the next view to appear
    if (...) 
        return nextViewController;
    else
        return nil;
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    //Check if the user is allowed to go back to the previous view -- some views are not possible to go back to

    //If all is good, allow for the previous view to appear
    if (...) 
        return previousViewController;
    else
        return nil;
}
```

I've built the *architecture* data-management stuff to make it work, and all is good. But, the UIPageViewController caches my data-source answers where I've said "no, there's no previous/next view...", which means that when the user has filled out what needed to be done and is granted access to proceed, it doesn't matter how much swiping is done; the cache says there's nothing there to swipe to.

So, I need to find a way of resetting the cache, enforcing the UIPageViewController to *always* ask the data-source if there's any view available, both before an after the current one.

I've dug around a bit, and found a nice approach that I thought could work, by re-assigning the datasource which enforce a "cache-reset";

```
//Enforce a cache reset after 1 sec
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    //Reset/reassign data source, which will cause cached data-VCs to be thrown
    DDLogInfo(@"Resetting data source");
    self.dataSource = nil;
    self.dataSource = self;
});
```

But, I can't find a suitable place for it to be executed, since when the data source is reset/reassigned, any ongoing animations due to gestures/swipes, will also be reset, which results in a poor UI.

I'd like to be able to find a suitable place to reset the datasource where I *know* that there is no ongoing animation. But the delegate `pageViewController:didFinishAnimating:previousViewControllers:transitionCompleted:` is only called if there's a view to scroll to. And, in my case if the user is at the currently "last" view, the view will be "dragged" but no new view is available.

Or, a different solution is to disable the UIPageViewController's "dragging" animations at the first/last view... I dunno -- stuck and in need of 2nd opinion ;) Any ideas/suggestions?

Best, 
/Markus

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset cache from `UIPageViewController` use this category

`UIPageViewController+Additions.h`:

```
@interface UIPageViewController (Additions)

- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers
                 direction:(UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection)direction
           invalidateCache:(BOOL)invalidateCache
                  animated:(BOOL)animated
                completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion;

@end
```

`UIPageViewController+Additions.m`

```
@implementation UIPageViewController (Additions)
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers direction:(UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection)direction invalidateCache:(BOOL)invalidateCache animated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion {
    NSArray *vcs = viewControllers;
    __weak UIPageViewController *mySelf = self;

    if (invalidateCache && self.transitionStyle == UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll) {
        UIViewController *neighborViewController = (direction == UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                                    ? [self.dataSource pageViewController:self viewControllerBeforeViewController:viewControllers[0]]
                                                    : [self.dataSource pageViewController:self viewControllerAfterViewController:viewControllers[0]]);
        [self setViewControllers:@[neighborViewController] direction:direction animated:NO completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [mySelf setViewControllers:vcs direction:direction animated:animated completion:completion];
        }];
    }
    else {
        [mySelf setViewControllers:vcs direction:direction animated:animated completion:completion];
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: so if I understand things correctly, calling `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:` enforce a cache reset? And this `Additions` category add a utility function to basically set/reset the currently visible view? I don't quite get the `neighborViewController` stuff, as I would like to just use the *current* view, not the next/previous when clearing the cache?

Comment: With that method from category you can set `UIViewController` and if you need force to reset cache data from `UIPageViewController` base on parameter value `invalidateCache`.

Comment: I just dislike to use code-snippets that I don't understand the purpose of... ;) Hence, my question on *why* this reset the cache of a `UIPageViewController` -- it must be that the `setViewControllers:...` implicitly cause the controller to reset the cache, or? And, if so, why use the neighbor views and not the `current` as reference?

Comment: I was reading about `UIPageViewController` cache and in general it is working wired. If you will set current `UIViewController` from code i.e. you have 4 viewcontrollers and you set "go to thridViewController" from first one then `UIPageViewController` will render new VC but when you will try to go to second `UIViewController` (by slide gesture) then will be render first one, even if you have setup data source correctly, in addition the method beforeViewController from data source will be never called. To summarise you have to set all 3 `UIViewControllers` to clean cache.